# Clock with 2 different times

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible in Minecraft (I'm using CraftBook) to make a timer with 2 different times? E.g First time a pulse goes out after 5 seconds, then it waits 20 seconds before the next pulse, then repeats. 5, 20, 5, 20 etc...?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that comes to mind is a setup like [this.](http://gyazo.com/d2ef501bc3b665cf7c1c2ffe901dc4fa)

Two different timers that both converge into one line of redstone leading to where ever you want it to go.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use command blocks (which can be given via /give [player name] 137 1), or you may have to create a mod of your own with that feature. Sorry that this isn't a specific answer. I will do some research and get back with you.

Comment: I didnt think this was possible, and I don't really want to use command blocks, I'll do some playing with redstone later see if I can come up with something too, I just didn't want to recreate the wheel if somebody else already knew how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A [hopper clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit#Hopper_clock) has an analog output (just grab the signal from the comparators you use anyway). You can combine this with a device that turns on only for a specific signal strength, like the one generikb uses in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aHjLwgDw-Q).

That way, you get an increasing signal, pulsing once when a specific strength is reached. When the signal retracts, it pulses again. The timing between these pulses can be configured seperately by changing the amount and type of items in the hopper, as well as the distance between the comparator and the detector (mostly trial and error). I suggest using eggs or snowballs (or any other block that stacks only to 16), so that the change in signal strength per item is larger.